# jQuery's Request To Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++, syntax, error-handling

Okay so look at these to alert()s. Here is the full code:

```
function OfficialFacebookLikes(Title)
{
    $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/'+Title, function(data) {
         alert(data['likes'].toString()); //<<temp
         return data['likes'].toString();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ui-btn').click(function(){ //cocacola
        var LikeCount = OfficialFacebookLikes("cocacola");
        alert(LikeCount);
    });
});
```

Why does

```
alert(LikeCount)
```

display (which is "undefined" when displayed) before

```
alert(data['likes'].toString())
```

I called the function `OfficialFacebookLikes` before I called the `alert(LikeCount)`. Could someone please explain why this is occurring. If my thought process isn't making since.. I'm use to coding in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.getJSON` function is asynchronous, this means that it needs a callback to call when it's finished, otherwise you'll never know when the function has been completed. Asynchronous functions run separately from the rest of the code.

When you call `OfficialFacebookLikes("cocacola")` it will call the `.getJSON` function. Now the `.getJSON` functions starts by its own and doesn't stop the script, so right after calling `OfficialFacebookLikes("cocacola")`, the next line of code is executed, which is actually `alert(LikeCount)`. But `LikeCount` has not yet been defined, since that `.getJSON` is still working.

When `.getJSON` finishes working the callback function given in `$.getJSON(..., function() {... })` gets executed, and then the `LikeCount` variable gets defined. So if you want to alert `LikeCount` you have to put the `alert()` inside the callback of `.getJSON`.

Comment: I will also add that LikeCount is undefined, and will always be so, because there is no return value from the function.  The OP's attempt to get a value for LikeCount using this code will always fail, regardless of whether the AJAX has called back or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is an asynchronous Ajax call.  You won't have data available until the call returns.  In your document ready code, you are attempting to alert the call immediately.

Instead, do whatever you need to do with the result set in the callback handler of the ajax:

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/'+Title, function(data) {
         doSomethingWithMy(data);

    });
```